# Emscripten/NodeJS: Make the actual file-system available by default

Tags: c, node.js, emscripten

I want to compile a CLI application with Emscripten and just utilize the native filesystem layer so that the application can execute it's own test-suite.

I know that I could technically do this with a proper `EM_ASM` statement within the program's `main()` function. However, is there a way to tell Emscripten to make this available by default? I have seen a Github issue which suggested `-s NODERAWFS=1`, but it does not seem to work - or at least, as expected.

As far as I am aware of, I would have those options for making the native filesystem available to the program:

- Edit `main()` to have an `EM_ASM` statement which mounts the root via `NODEFS`.
- Add a pre-script which does the above but substracted from the original program.

The reason why I need the root mapped is due to the need of passing a path to the program to allow the program to find it's testsuite.

Any idea on how I could make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The source code (`settings.js`)](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/settings.js#L623) explains about `-s NODERAWFS=1` emcc compile option:

> The File System API will directly use Node.js API without requiring `FS.mount()`.  **The initial working directory will be same as process.cwd() instead of VFS root directory.**

This sounds like you probably need to use relative paths like `./` instead of the default root `/` for your working directory if you enable `-s NODERAWFS=1`?

Apart from that, `settings.js` has the best descriptions about emcc options than its official documentation. You probably want to dig into it.

Comment: It turns out that this flag worked all along. But appearently, the program can not scan the folder for it's test suite - yet, it runs individual files just fine. I'll have to look into this more - maybe I actually found a bug, who knows. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This sounds like https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/7487, opendir and directory listings not working with NODERAWFS=1